# Does Hazelcast Jet support rolling number as IMap key, with Kafka as a source?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I've used Hazelcast some time ago, and I'm using Hazelcast Jet for the first time and seems interesting for processing some real-time streaming, exploring through.

Here I have a situation, I'm pulling `Kafka topic` to `IMap` using:

```java
private static Pipeline buildPipelineForClientDataa() {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
        p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(
                props("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, 
                        "key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getCanonicalName(), 
                        "value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getCanonicalName(), 
                        "auto.offset.reset", AUTO_OFFSET_RESET), 
                KAFKA_TOPIC))
        .withoutTimestamps()
        .drainTo(Sinks.map(SINK_CLINET_DATA));
        return p;
    }
```

Well, I've no Key for the topic. Should I've an option to assign rolling number as a key? If so, help me with the technique. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using incrementing number isn't a good match for Jet because it's a distributed system. It works with a partitioned stream and each stream partition should be independent. You would need to route all items through a non-parallel processor.

You could use `UUID` or Hazelcast's `FlakeIdGenerator` as the key, but if the job restarts and re-processes the Kafka topic from a snapshotted offset, the same items will have a different key assigned and will be present twice in the target map.

If you want to have each item in the map, you can use Kafka's topic+partitionId+offset combination as the key:

```java
p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(
    props(...),
    record -> Util.entry(
        Tuple3.tuple3(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset()),
        record.value()),
    KAFKA_TOPIC))
```

You can omit the topic if you have just one topic.

Comment: Is this the org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils you put up in the code? If so, there's no method entry supported.

Comment: It's `com.hazelcast.jet.Util.entry()`, not `Utils`, I fixed the response. `Map.Entry` is required for `Sinks.map()`.

Comment: I'm confused. Please help me embed Map.Entry in Sinks.map(). Is some iteration required to insert into map? With just a Sinks.map(map_name); the error reporting is ClassCastException from Tulip to String.

Comment: @srikanth Ask a new question and share your code. The `Sinks.map` expects `Map.Entry` instances on its input, but you should get a compile-time error when not doing that.